# creating a sliderview which covers 75% of screen ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, slidingmenu

I am creating an application which is my 1st application and creating it **without storyboard**. The main screen contains tabbarcontroller with different views and header of that main view has button. When clicked on that button there should be a view which should be coming from left side of screen sliding in and should occupy 75% of the screenspace and rest of mainview with tabbarcontroller should occupy remaining 25%. The sliding view should appear with bounce.

As i am beginner and this is my 1st application i am not able to workaround things for implementing the above scenario.

Following is the image attached which is created by me for android app. I want to create same in IOS 7.

[image]

I am not using Storyboard.

Comment: There are tons of demos and SDKs for iOS, like this on the web, since you are a beginner as you said why not to start from a working lib and customize it?.